# Woocommerce get all products in array

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Im having problems with retrieving product infos trough object functions in Woocommerce.

This is how I do:

```
public function table_data()
{
    $args     = array( 'post_type' => 'product', 'posts_per_page' => -1 );
    $products = get_posts( $args );

    $pfactory = new WC_Product_Factory();
    foreach($products as $product)
    {
        $_product = $pfactory->get_product($product);
    }
}
```

This returns product informations from wp_posts only, it won't give me the information stored in wp_postmeta.

I need the full information from all products (such as price, sku, stock etc.) in one array, but I seem to be missing something and Im unsure if it has with the hierarchy of the functions in my code. However I thought this was possible to do without SQL-queries.

Basicly, what im trying to do is a complete duplicate of product list in admin for listing products with information in the panel.

Thanks for all the help I can get.

Answer (score 11):

Use WP_Query instead, which will give you access to the global WooCommerce $product variable from within the loop. From there, you can grab the price, sku, stock and all other kinds of data. http://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Product.html

```
<?php
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'posts_per_page' => -1
    );
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    if ( $loop->have_posts() ): while ( $loop->have_posts() ): $loop->the_post();

        global $product;

        $price = $product->get_price_html();
        $sku = $product->get_sku();
        $stock = $product->get_stock_quantity();

    endwhile; endif; wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Comment: What's not working? What are you trying? This code is not yet outputting anything, rather giving you the variables you need to output the data.

Comment: Im doing a simple test with your example code where i try to var_dump some parameters. But i can't understand why you use $product-> in your example?

Comment: From Woocommerce docs - "calling the_post() will automatically populate the global $product variable if the post is a product." http://docs.woothemes.com/document/class-reference/. The WooCommerce product class handles individual product data. Print the $product array within the loop to see what you have to work with.

Comment: Yes, thats exactly what I red earlier today. But the only info i get is: Notice: Undefined variable: product

Comment: var_dump($product);die; within the loop returns NULL right now.

Comment: try adding $product = wc_get_product( $post->ID );

Comment: Ok, quick update. If I add following in the loop: global $product; var_dump($product);die; I do retrieve an array, but this array doesn't contain information such as sku, price etc. :/

Comment: Darn, im spamming you (sorry). But now i can see that if I use your $price = $product->get_price_html(); it works!!!

Answer (score 4):

First thing I came up with was this.

```
function products() {
        return array_map('wc_get_product', get_posts(['post_type'=>'product','nopaging'=>true]));
}
```

I'd love to know from someone more experienced with WooCommerce if there is a better way

Answer (score 0):

As of WooCommerce 3 you can do it using the [wc_get_products](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/files/woocommerce-includes-wc-product-functions.html) function like this:

```
  $args = array(
    'status' => 'publish',
    'orderby' => 'title',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'limit' => -1,
  );
  $products = wc_get_products($args);
  if (count($products) > 0) {
    foreach ($products as $product) {
      echo $product->get_id() . '<br>';
      echo $product->get_name() . '<br>';
      echo $product->get_price_html() . '<br>';
      echo $product->get_sku() . '<br>';
      echo $product->get_stock_quantity() . '<br>';
    }
  }
```

Comment: Just realised this is similar to what Tim is doing in answer below, but will leave it here in case it's helpful for people to see the full code.